# What are some good ideas on how to Map a Replace function over a list of equations?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I've been working on a rather simple implimination of parameterizing a 3D line in space, and now am trying to find a way to map different values of `t` over those equations. The only approaches I've tried so far have a lot of negative side effects and complications. Advice is appreciated because I need to find the points on a lot of lines by segmentation. :) Thanks.

```
 {u,i} = {{2099,1313,4599},{-21208,-1146,4697}}

 f[x] = (i[[1]]-u[[1]]) t + u[[1]];
 f[y] = (i[[2]]-u[[2]]) t + u[[2]];
 f[z] = (i[[3]]-u[[3]]) t + u[[3]];

 {f[x],f[y],f[z]} /. t->.5
 {-9554.5,83.5,4648.}
```

Comment: The expressions `f[x]=`, `f[y]=`, and `f[z]=` are syntactically correct but are not customary. In any case, can you give some examples of the negative side effects you want to avoid?

Comment: Well briefly... one side effect is that I don't know exactly how to do that? (As you could probably already tell from my non-customary expression.) Perhaps someone will enlighten me as to the standard way to express these terms in their answer?

Comment: As you do not use `x` as a argument of the function, but `f[x]` is just a name you could jist write `fx=`, `fy=`, `fz=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set values of `t` to be from `1,2,...10` using `Range`

```
{u, i} = {{2099, 1313, 4599}, {-21208, -1146, 4697}};

f[x] = (i[[1]] - u[[1]]) t + u[[1]];
f[y] = (i[[2]] - u[[2]]) t + u[[2]];
f[z] = (i[[3]] - u[[3]]) t + u[[3]];

{fNumericX, fNumericY, fNumericZ} = {f[x], f[y], f[z]} /. t -> Range[1, 10]
```

Your expression works if `t` should be a vector. The values of each coordinate are saved as vectors in `fNumericX`, `fNumericY`, and `fNumericZ`

In more complex cases it might not work and and you might want to look up how `Map` and `Table` could be used for the same purpose.

Somewhat more elegant code for solving the same task using `Map`

```
{fNumericX, fNumericY, fNumericZ} = 
 Transpose@Map[(t \[Function] (i - u) t + u), Range[1, 10]]
```